# zypper always going to background. How to restore stdin?

Tags: opensuse, zypper

I'm upgrading 11.4 to 12.1. What's annoying in `zypper dup` is that after about a minute it goes background. Output to console is still active, but I lose the ability to do stdin. A message appears saying

```
[1]+ Stopped zypper dup
```

or something like that. I can't do anything when zypper prompts me something. I tried doing `fg` but I get

```
zypper dup

[1]+  Stopped                 zypper dup

[1]+  Stopped                 zypper dup
```

How can I restore stdin to zypper or at least tell it to go ahead with retry command?

Comment: Do you have `cpulimit` installed?

Comment: No, because I didn't intentionally install it *and* zypper se cpulimit says the package is not found

Comment: By the way, I'm on a VPS box. Could the company have installed it into the kernel or something like that? I didn't know cpulimit since now

Comment: Eh, I'm not sure about it. I was just asking because of similar symptoms.